# Какие из средств Visual Studio добавляют поддержку COM библиотек?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, sdk

Есть COM SDK одной программы (4-е .dll-ки). На WIN10_64 подключить не удалось, ошибка

> убедитесь что файл доступен и является допустимой сборкой или компонентом com

на WIN7_32 при первой попытке установки VS удалось добавить через refernce и пользоваться этой библиотекой (даже скриншот успешного подключения сохранился). Т.е. подключилось без всех DLLImport и Invoke Какие из компонентов помимо дефолтных были загружены - не вспомню.

Понадобилось переустановить виртуалку и соответсвенно сбился VS. При двух повторных попытках - та же ошибка что и в WIN10. Т.е. если я не туплю, то выходит что какие-то из компонентов и отвечают за подключение COM SDK

Но какие?

Comment: А Com сборки зарегистрированы через спец. утилиту?

Comment: @iluxa1810 Если Вы про отдельную вкладку COM в выборе ссылок, то нет. Добавляю локально, с жесткого диска

Answer (score 1):

Очень похоже что немного кривые сборки, и после переустановки (sdk компонентов) удалось запустить даже на win10 (хотя сис. требования вообще